# Set model property from bootstrap 3 modal without post back

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to update object model property from a partial view using bootstrap modal. I am able to update hidden value on main form and can see it in model property after post back but I want to set that property value without post back. The reason behind is that I am making use of the value while reopening the modal form but its not available as model is not yet post back.

Hidden control for model feature id:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectLocation.FeatureID, new { @id = "featureId" })
```

Anchor tag for partial view:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ShowMap", "Map", new { requestId = Model.ID, featureId = Model.ProjectLocation.FeatureID })" class="btn btn-default modal-link" id="startMap" aria-label="Left Align">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span>SpecifyLocation
</a>
```

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowMap(string requestId, string featureId)
{
    var model = new MapFeature(requestId);
    model.FeatureID = featureId;

    return PartialView("ShowMap", model);
}
```

Here is my partial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowMapPost", "Map", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmMap" }))
{
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
        <h4>DrawProjectLocation</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FeatureID, new { id = "selectedFeatureID" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RequestID)

        <div id="mainWindow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer"  data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:false" style="width:100%; height:100%;">       
            <div id="map" class="roundedCorners" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submitButton">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var frm = $("#frmMap");
        frm.submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("ShowMapPost", "Map")",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    FeatureID: frm.find('#selectedFeatureID').val()
                }),
                success: function (result) {
                    //or simply close our modal.
                    if (result) {
                        $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('LocationNotSelected');
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is javascript code which I am using while closing my modal form:

```
$('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    var value = $('#selectedFeatureID').val();
    $('#featureId').val(value);

    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

As you can see that I want to make use of property "Model.ProjectLocation.FeatureID" but its not available until I post back. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you using ajax call to save the  value.. when you closing the pop up you are saving the value its self `var value =$('#selectedFeatureID').val(); $('#featureId').val(value);`

Comment: no its not true. selectedFeatureID is on modal form while featureId is on my main form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it by adding a new partial view for child object and a get action on my controller for parent object. I passed serialized object to this action and updated my partial view.

Following is my code (might be helpful for users having the same issue)

**Render partial view in my main view:**

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Map/MapOpenPartial.cshtml", Model)
```

**Ajax call in main view:**

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '@Url.Action("testMe","MyObject")',
   cache: false,
   data: $("#this_form").serialize(),
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success: function (partialViewResult) {
         $("#trShowMap").html(partialViewResult);
   }
});
```

**Partial view:**

```
@model Graafgebiedinformatie.Models.MYOBJECT

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectLocation.FeatureID, new { @id = "featureId" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectLocation.RequestID)

<td>@Html.Label("SpecifyLocation")</td>
<td>
    <a href="@Url.Action("ShowMap", "Map", new { requestId = Model.ProjectLocation.RequestID, featureId = Model.FEATURE_GUID_REF })" class="btn btn-default modal-link" id="startMap" aria-label="Left Align">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> @Graafgebiedinformatie.Globalization.Resources.SpecifyLocation
    </a>
</td>
```

**Action on main controller:**

```
public ActionResult testMe(MYOBJECT model)
{
   return PartialView("~/Views/Map/MapOpenPartial.cshtml", model);
}
```